# How to use the DiffUtil with the RendererRecyclerViewAdapter library

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-recyclerview

To simplify work with `RecyclerView` I use the [RendererRecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/vivchar/RendererRecyclerViewAdapter) library, by samples I added [`Renderer`, `Model`, `ViewHolder`](https://github.com/vivchar/RendererRecyclerViewAdapter#usage).

To update a list I use two methods:

```
mAdapter.setItems(myList);
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

But I want to add the [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.html) to automatically add animations (adding, removing, moving).

How can I do it with this library?

Answer (score 0):

This library already supports the `DiffUtil`

1) In each of your classes that implement the `ItemModel` interface, add an implementation of the methods - `equals()` and `hashCode()`;

2) Call the `enableDiffUtil()` method after initialization of the Adapter

```
...
RendererRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RendererRecyclerViewAdapter();
adapter.enableDiffUtil();
...
```

3) Remove the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method

After calling the `setItems(myList)` method the library will automatically use the `DiffUtil`, no need to do anything more.